# String comparison in SQLite not working when string contains '&'

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, string-comparison

I'm losing my mind.  This query works fine (finds one matching record) when executed in SQLite Manager (FF plugin):

```
SELECT * FROM VendorDB WHERE lower(CompanyName) = 'b&b'
```

But this variablized SELECT statement (which is exactly the same as above when echo'd out) doesn't find anything.

```
SELECT * FROM VendorDB WHERE lower(CompanyName) = [vendor variable containing 'b&b]
```

When the string does not contain an '&' both queries work the same.  I've googled all over and not been able to find anything about why the query shouldn't work consistently.

BTW, I'm using PHP:PDO to execute the query.

EDIT_1:
Here's how the query is being handled (after implementing the suggestions from @Phil), where $dbh is the database connection:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM VendorDB WHERE lower(CompanyName) = ?"; 
//[$vendor is the variable containing 'b&b]


$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$go_fetch = $dbh->prepare($qry);
$go_fetch->bindParam(1,$vendor);
$go_fetch->execute();
```

and the results are retrieved as:

```
$go_fetch->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$data = $go_fetch->fetchAll();
```

All of which yields an empty array, but should yield one and only one record.

Also note that I've echo'd the value of the variable $vendor prior to being inserted into the query and it is the *correct* value (i.e. 'b&b'  not `'b&amp;b'`)

Comment: is the & perhaps the html entity `&amp;` ?

Comment: _“which is exactly the same as above when echo'd out”_ – are you _sure_ … that it is not maybe `&amp;` in your second query?

Comment: Where is the value coming from and how are you injecting it into the query? You should be binding it using `bindParam` / `bindValue` or passing it into the `execute` method

Comment: @dagon yes, that's my concern that the & is being converted to $amp; but I can't seem to find where that's happening

Comment: @CBroe.  am I sure? well, all I did to test _the query_ was to take the echo output and copy/paste it into SQLite Manager to see what it found...and it found exactly what I expected it to find...  I understand this isn't the same as seeing what goes on behind the scenes when that query is submitted to the PDO engine...

Comment: @ Phil I am passing the query via execute. I'll amend my question with the PDO handling...

Comment: @globalSchmidt That's not what I said. I said *"You should be binding it (the **value**) using `bindParam` / `bindValue` or passing it (again, the **value**) into the execute method"*. Also, when you `echo` things out to an HTML page, you may not be seeing the **real** value. View the page source to see what's truly being displayed.

Comment: You also haven't explained where the `$vendor` value comes from.

Comment: @Phil - apologies for misinterpreting your question. I'm new to PDO. Your answer below helped me improve my code. Didn't expect to receive a down vote just for not realizing there was a better way to code.  I've resolved my problem...  see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the issue.  It was a stupid error on my part, but memorializing the answer here in case its useful to someone else.

The problem was indeed that the '&' sign was being converted into '&'. (Thanks @CBroe for the clue!) It was hard to detect because it wasn't showing up in any of the browser output I was looking at (including viewing the page source).

Long ago and far away I had forgotten that I had set up a standard form-handling function to "cleanse" all POST data.  One line in that function took each posted value and applied the htmlspecialchars() function to it.  This converted the 'b&b' into 'b&b'.  Great for the HTML echo'd output, not so good for database comparison strings.

For this particular application, if I do not apply the htmlspecialchars() everything works as expected, regardless of the way that PDO is implemented.

Lesson re-learned... never forget the "defaults" you establish!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment above, use a proper parameterised statement. For example...

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM VendorDB WHERE lower(CompanyName) = ?"; 
$go_fetch = $dbh->prepare($qry);
```

Then, either pass the parameter in to the `execute` method

```
$go_fetch->execute([$vendor]);
```

or bind it first, then execute

```
$go_fetch->bindParam(1, $vendor);
$go_fetch->execute();
```

I doubt very much that the ampersand is causing any issues. I can't find any reference to it as an SQLite special character.

I'd say the issue is either that the value in fact contains `b&amp;b` or that it contains other problem characters like `'`. The former indicates a problem with where and how the `$vendor` variable is set. The latter is solved by my answer above.